SSIS package designed in VS2010 not working in a 2019 SQL Server
I have a SSIS project/packages written in VS2010, that has a number of c# custom script tasks, I tried to deploy to a 2019 SQL Server for the first time but it fails, gives an error message "... Failed to compiled scripts contain in the package. Open the package in SSIS Designer and resolve the compilation errors." I know this not a new issue just that someone out there might be armed with more knowledge.
Now, besides the fact someone in the past from Microsoft had bad gramma and had no vision of the future simply put it ain't working. Do I really have to upgrade to VS2019 first and the more pertinent question how as I read some posts you are better off to go VS2015 first than work your way up - but like how many versions do I need to install or in some cases might be better to start from scratch and copy and paste your code over to 2019 until it works but, is there anything I can ask support to check on the server or is it a case I have to stop flogging a dead horse and upgrade.
Closest post I have found so far that represents my issue: SSIS - package works in VS, fails with "Failed to compiled scripts contained in the package". There are no script objects in the package
I have also since tried converting well I dont know if what I did was right, but I was able to open my package in VS2019 and I was able to set the TargetServerVersion to 2019, is there more to it?? Anyhow, it ran ok in VS2019 but after I deployed and ran, it said missing microsoft libraries which maybe I have to install something on the server. The libraries I used were from the GAC (e.g. Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices) and they are not installed on the server so now I ask you the question how do I install? Is there an SDK package or something if some can provide the link where to download and install for the server. Why doesn't the deploy process include the libraries or at least check and thru an error.
